# Rails: what code should go in model and service class when following PORO(plain old ruby object) structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-4

I have gone through several documentations available online on PORO concepts and have understood that why we should we use PORO but what i didn't understand is that if businesses logic should go in service classes then what should go in activerecord model class??

Also in what cases it doesn't make sense to create service class and instead should be write code in activerecord model classes??

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "PORO structure"? Your question is about as vague as asking "how do I write good code?" -- This is a huge topic, of much debate, that cannot possibly be succinctly answered in a single StackOverflow post. There are thousands of books written on the topic.

Comment: A good place to start is to read about SOLID principles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) -- such as the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: As a somewhat vague answer to your question, the best I can say is: Your code should be "clean and simple". A class should have a **single responsibility**. The primary purpose of service objects is to abstract complex logic into a customised structure of classes; so as to make it flexible, reusable and testable in isolation.

Comment: Model classes in ActiveRecord have tons of responsibilies even with no or very little code. They handle associations, validations, callbacks, db scopes etc. The key  point here is that its not about distributing the lines of code - its about avoiding making your models even more god-like.

Answer (score 0):

This article will completely answer your questions and leave you more than satisfied: [Extreme Rails Decoupling with POROs](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/decoupling-rails-components).

In summary, POROs can be used in different ways in Rails:

1. Service Objects: This are stateless objects and may have side effects on its dependencies. They are usually utilized when we need to interact with external services such as processing billing for users and then sending an email after that, or publishing to a queue etc. Their isolation allows for easy testability.
2. Interactors: This is a technical term for the Ruby object that is used to perform a given use case. These classes usually have an actionable name(i.e a verb). Example of such class can be `ChargePendingUsers`
3. Value Objects: These are immutable objects which represents very simple entity whose equality is not based on identity. A very common example for this will be a `Money` class which can tell both its currency and then its amount.
4. Query Objects: This just abstracts the query responsibility from the AR model, keeping your classes light. They are usually used when the underlying query logic is complex
5. Presenters: These objects most times inherit from SimpleDelegator and help keep our views free from logic. They implement the decorator pattern and add more functionality to the underlying object.